# Python uiautomator crash after enable USB tethering

Tags: python, python-3.x, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use uiautomator to enable USB tethering on Android. However, it will throw urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError after USB tethering is turned on. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

I write except to catch this error but it will disable USB tethering by itself when crash. It means I still fail to turn on USB tethering.

```py
import uiautomator
d = uiautomator.Device('serial number', 5555)
d(text='USB tethering').right(className='android.widget.Switch').click()
print('succeed')
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 265, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.py", line 1009, in switch_tethered
    d(text='USB tethering').right(className='android.widget.Switch').click()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator\__init__.py", line 76, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator\__init__.py", line 971, in _click
    return self.jsonrpc.click(self.selector)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator\__init__.py", line 443, in wrapper
    return _JsonRPCMethod(url, method, timeout, False)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator\__init__.py", line 438, in wrapper
    return _method_obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator\__init__.py", line 119, in __call__
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 323, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 265, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer. uiautomator does not update anymore. uiautomator2 can solve this bug.